# Core Data Reading Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am a VERY new beginner to Core Data and I have recently been trying to read and write data. I created an entity named "Person" with the entities "name" and "age". I also have a textfield name "personName" and a textfield named "personAge".

```
- (IBAction)readData:(id)sender
{
    NSNumber *ageNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:personAge.text.integerValue];
    Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    newPerson.name = personName.text;
    newPerson.age = ageNum;

    NSLog(@"Person %@ name is %@", personName.text, ageNum);
}
```

When I load the app, all i get is SIGABRT. Even when all I put in the method is

```
 Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: make sure your `managedObjectContext` is not `nil`

Comment: Here's something interesting. Whenever I pull a core data object and read it from my app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it works, but whenever I put ANY core data code into an IBAction it crashes. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

For Adding values to the core data you can do so:-

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [person setValue:self.personName.text forKey:@"name"];
    [person setValue:self.personAge.text forKey:@"age"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }    
}
```

For fetching the values from core data:-

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    self.personValues = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

here personValues is a NSMutableArray.
For better understanding about these please go through this link.

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very new to Core Data, try using the [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) library which provides a series of helper categories for dealing with a lot of the boiler plate setup of Core Data.

Which brings me to the question you are asking: are you sure your Core Data stack is being setup correctly?  Check to make sure your Managed Object Context is valid along with a proper Persistent Store Coordinator.

Best thing to do: put a breakpoint during the Core Data stack setup and step through it making sure everything is setup properly.  Or install MagicalRecord and do one method call to [MagicalRecord setupAutomigratingCoreDataStack]...